# Fragments seem to be stacking on top of each other - causing problems, android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I've been pulling my hair out over this for the whole day, as I'm very new to fragments. Basically, I have a fragment in an app I have that keeps track of a player's currency. I want to reuse one fragment throughout the entire app, as it has references to a singleton class that stores the players currency and sets a TextView to display this currency.

The problem is that in every activity I initialize a new fragment when the activity starts, like so:

```java
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fmang2, new fragment1());
        ft.commit();
```

this causes the fragments to stack, which is a problem because the fragments are constantly adding currency to the player's balance. So, if I have 3 created 3 activities, players will be receiving currency 3x as fast as they should be.

How do I fix this? I've tried creating fragments with XML too, but that doesn't help.
For reference, here is the code in my fragment:

```java
package com.example.bunzclicker;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import com.example.bunzclicker.bunz.Bunz;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class fragment1 extends Fragment {
    private TextView bunz_count;
    private TextView money_count;
    private Bunz bunz;
    private Handler handler;
    private HandlerThread mHandlerThread;
    int delay = 1000;
    View view;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        bunz = Bunz.getInstance();
        handler = new Handler();


        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);



        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                update(view);
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }, delay);






        return view;
    }





    public void update(View view){
        bunz_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.final_bunz_count);
        money_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.final_money_count);
        //System.out.println(bunz.getBaker1());


        BigDecimal number = ((BigDecimal.valueOf
                (bunz.getBaker1()).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(.1))));
//        ).add((BigDecimal.valueOf(bunz.getBaker2()).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(.2)))).
//                add((BigDecimal.valueOf
//                        (bunz.getBaker3()).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(.4)))).
//                add((BigDecimal.valueOf
//                        (bunz.getBaker4()).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(.8)))).
//                add((BigDecimal.valueOf(bunz.getBaker5()).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1)))).
//                add((BigDecimal.valueOf(bunz.getBaker6()).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(2)))).
//                add((BigDecimal.valueOf(bunz.getBaker7()).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(4)))).
//                add((BigDecimal.valueOf(bunz.getBaker8()).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(5)))).
                //add((BigDecimal.valueOf(bunz.getBaker9()).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(10))));
        //System.out.println(number);
        bunz.setBunz(bunz.getBunz().add((number)));
        bunz_count.setText("Bunz: " + bunz.getBunz());
        money_count.setText("Money: " + bunz.getMoney());
        System.out.println("bunz" + bunz.getBunz());

    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should not add currency when fragment is being created, you can i.e use an boolean extra to indicate when you should add curreny at fragment creation

Comment: hmm what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, you're doing right re-using fragments, that's great but the problem isn't the fact that the fragment is being created on every activity, the problem is in your logic itself. You know how intent extras works? You can create a flag to check if you should add currency or not, that way you can create the fragment 3 times but add currency just once

Comment: Yeah I know about intent extras, but I'm not sure how I'd use that here. The way I have it set up, it's just automatically incrementing the currency 24/7. Is there something I need to fix with that?

Comment: You're doing this on setBunz method right? you should add currency just when your boolean extra in your fragment is true, otherwise you just load the user currency, so in all your acitivties you must instantiate your fragment with this extra telling the fragmnet when to add currnecy or just load the previous one

Comment: Figured it out, thanks though! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Handler` keeps posting `update()` even when the fragment has been put on pause, you should move the handler code to `onResume()` and use `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` in `onPause` to prevent `update()` calls when the fragment is paused. You'll need to do something along the following lines,

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            update(view);
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Throughout time, there have been heroes. You sir, are one of them.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've spent the whole day on this.